# Why does my neural network perform poorly when trained on a large dataset, despite working well on a small one?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have an RNN, which I am training to generate text. When trained on a small dataset, it performed very well (though it did memorise chunks of text from the training data, suggesting overfitting). However, on a large dataset, it performs very poorly, outputting only a few sensible words before getting stuck in a loop of the same three or four words. I am aware that overfitting could be a problem, however surely this would not result in such abysmal performance when trained on the large dataset as compared to the fairly good performance when trained on a small dataset. Any ideas as to what could be causing these results?

Comment: I think your problem is efficiency. It simply doesn't scale well...

Comment: @ProEvilz What do you mean by "efficiency"?

Comment: can you share your RNN architecture?

Answer (score 1):

i think its a good idea to add  Long Short Term Memory(LSTM) if you haven't added one. Please see the link for reference.
https://medium.com/@camrongodbout/recurrent-neural-networks-for-beginners-7aca4e933b82